# How to remove budgie environment safely?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, budgie

I've changed my OS from Windows to Ubuntu for my very first time. I chose the Budgie desktop environment because it looked really pretty to me.

After a while, I installed `gnome-desktop` via `apt install gnome-desktop` and I don't need Budgie any more.

How can I remove the Budgie environment safely with all components from Budgie? My system is encrypted by Ubuntu.